# Why my font family aint working in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, text, font-family

Everything seems working just fine except the font family.Text animation is working but everytime i run my Flutter apps it runs on the normal default font.What should i do now?

```
children: [
        AnimatedTextKit(
          animatedTexts: [
            TypewriterAnimatedText(
              'Hello world!',
              textStyle: const TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 32.0,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  fontFamily: 'Canterbury'
              ),
              speed: const Duration(milliseconds: 200),
            ),
          ],

          totalRepeatCount: 4,
          pause: const Duration(milliseconds: 1000),
          displayFullTextOnTap: true,
          stopPauseOnTap: true,
        )
      ],
    )
  ),
);
```

}
}

Comment: have you included font `assets` in `yaml` file?

Comment: No i did not,,can you please tell me what should i add...i only  found google font assets in web..I thought flutter have built in function for basic font

Comment: Check this https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/design/fonts

Comment: show your pubspec.yml as we can't assume is loaded correctly. Also your folder structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to add the fonts to your pubspec.yaml file. Here is an example of how to properly implement them assuming the file storing your fonts is in the root folder of your project (not the lib)

```
assets:
...
  fonts:
    - family: Schyler
      fonts:
        - asset: fonts/Schyler-Regular.ttf
        - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
          style: italic
```